# ffmpeg: Почему отключается трансляция из нескольких видео?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, потоки-данных, ffmpeg

Здраствуйте, у нас есть 24/7 трансляция, которая крутит по кругу 5-6 видео, которые по 8 часов
Для этой задачи мы взяли ffmpeg, написали простенький bash скрипт

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#Standard Options
RESOLUTION="1280x720" #Video resolution
FPS="60"
BITRATE="4500k"
PRESET_LIBX264="veryfast" #Speed libx256
server='rtmp://server.example.com'

vidFile='./videos.txt'

if [[ "$USER" != "root" ]]; then echo -e "\033[31mError user\033[0m"; exit 0; fi

rtmp="$server/keyBlablabla"

if [[ "$1" == "start" ]]; then
        screen -S stream -d -m ffmpeg -re -vsync 1 -f concat -safe 0 -i $vidFile -c:v libx264 -preset $PRESET_LIBX264 -b:v $BITRATE -minrate $BITRATE -maxrate $BITRATE -bufsize $BITRATE -s $RESOLUTION -r $FPS -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv -c copy $rtmp
        echo -e "\033[32mСтрим запущен.\033[0m"
        exit 0
elif [[ "$1" == "kill" ]]; then
        screen -X -S stream kill
        echo -e "\033[32mСтрим остановлен\033[0m"
        exit 0
elif [[ "$1" == "ls" ]]; then
        echo $(screen -ls)
        exit 0
fi
```

Вот собственно ffmpeg команда

```
ffmpeg -re -vsync 1 -f concat -safe 0 -i ./videos.txt -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 4500k -minrate 4500k -maxrate 4500k -bufsize 4500k -s 1280x720 -r 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv -c copy 'rtmp://server.example.com/keyBlablabla'
```

Раньше этот код работал, НО, велись некие работы, обновляли ПО и версию ОС
У нас Ubuntu 20.04
Версия ffmpeg:

```
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

И содержимое файла videos.txt:

```
file '/root/videos/v1.mp4'
file '/root/videos/v2.mp4'
file '/root/videos/v3.mp4'
file '/root/videos/v4.mp4'
```

**НО сейчас, ffmpeg, стал вести себя странно, и после того как видео v1.mp4 заканчивается, он не запускает v2.mp4, а просто падает и выключается.**

Для запуска используем команду **./stream.sh start**, для выключения  **./stream.sh kill**, это для удобства использования.

Не подскажете как поправить? Или как это дело можно залогировать, чтоб понять в чём проблема?

Comment: Посмотри вывод screen при падении. Лучше запиши вывод ffmpeg в лог

Comment: ПС.
Переходи на сервис systemd

Comment: ПС.
Конвертируй видео заранее и используй `-c:v copy`

Comment: "Посмотри вывод screen при падении. Лучше запиши вывод ffmpeg в лог" Каким образом можно вести лог?) Сделал сегодня через ">", но лог пустой создаётся
systemd наверное не очень тут подходит т.к стрим выключаем в 8 вечера каждый день, и включаем утром, хотя, можно подробнее?)

Comment: Можете записать как ответ, чтоб я пометил

Comment: ffmpeg для таких целей не годится. От слова совсем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри вывод screen при падении:

Команду выделяй в отдельный файл bash потому как в скрине там свой буфер ввода вывода и строчка команды больно большая чтоб не запутаться... Вывод ffmpeg в лог пишется со второго дескриптора `ffmpeg .... 2> error.log`

ПС.
Переходи на сервис systemd

При запуске с systemd лог уже пишется в журнал. Юнит запуска простой /etc/systemd/system/myff.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Ffmpeg service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ffmpeg ... ... 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Включать выключать можно через таймеры или по крону аналогично вышей обертке на скрине. Возможно сделать ещё лучше через ffserver, но там в конфиг вникать ещё надо.

ПС.
Конвертируй видео заранее и используй `-c:v copy` чтоб не греть воздух.

И я бы перешел на `hls` и вообще отказался от ffmpeg